# Sequential and parallel addition of 2 vectors

Tags: c++, multithreading, vectors

I have done sequential and parallel addition of 2 vectors that I have filled with some dummy values. I am also measuring the time of execution for both, sequential and parallel execution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <cassert>
#include <thread>

#define NUM_OF_THREADS 8
#define VECTOR_SIZE    512

using time_point = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point;

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> operator+(std::vector<T> const& first, std::vector<T> const& second)
{
    assert(first.size() == second.size());

    std::vector<T> result;
    result.reserve(first.size());

    std::transform(first.begin(), first.end(), second.begin(), std::back_inserter(result), std::plus<T>());
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
void parallel_addition(std::vector<T>& result,
                       std::vector<T> const& first,
                       std::vector<T> const& second,
                       size_t lower_bound,
                       size_t upper_bound)
{
    for (size_t i = lower_bound; i < upper_bound; i++)
    {
        result[i] = first[i] + second[i];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> first_vec, second_vec;

    /* Filling up the vectors with dummy values */
    for (int i = 1; i <= VECTOR_SIZE; i++)
    {
        first_vec.push_back(i);
        second_vec.push_back(i);
    }

    /* Sequential addition of vectors */
    time_point t1_seq = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::vector<int> sequential_result = first_vec + second_vec;
    time_point t2_seq = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_seq = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2_seq - t1_seq).count();
    std::cout << "Sequential addition of vectors - execution time: " << duration_seq << "us" << std::endl;

    /* Parallel addition of vectors */
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::vector<int> parallel_result(VECTOR_SIZE);

    time_point t1_par = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS; i++)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(parallel_addition<int>,
                                      std::ref(parallel_result),
                                      first_vec,
                                      second_vec,
                                      i * (VECTOR_SIZE / NUM_OF_THREADS),
                                      (i + 1) * (VECTOR_SIZE / NUM_OF_THREADS)));
    }

    for (auto &thread : threads)
    {
        thread.join();
    }

    time_point t2_par = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_par = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2_par - t1_par).count();
    std::cout << "Parallel (" << NUM_OF_THREADS << " threads) addition of vectors - execution time: " << duration_par << "us" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Despite style review, can you also tell me if there is another, better, approach to addition of two vectors in multiple threads?
My intention was to write in C++17.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the points are already mentioned by others, thus I will only tell you my opinion about the missing ones.

I don't really like your `parallel_addition` function. You obviously know how to use `std algorithms`, why don't you simply use them for your purpose?
It all boils down to something like that:

```
auto range = std::size(first_vec) / NUM_OF_THREADS;
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS; i++)
{
    auto start = i * range;
    auto firstBegin = std::begin(first_vec) + start;
    auto secondBegin = std::begin(second_vec) + start;
    auto resultBegin = std::begin(parallel_result) + start;

    auto firstEnd = firstBegin + range;
    threads.emplace_back(
        [firstBegin, firstEnd, secondBegin, resultBegin]()
        {
            std::transform(firstBegin, firstEnd, secondBegin, resultBegin, std::plus<int>());
        }
    );
}
```

Be aware of the fact, that you have to take care for the cases, where your vector size isn't a multiplication of thread count. There will be some elements left untouched, but I let this job as a task for you ;)

### `vector::emplace_back`

I prefer `emplace_back` over `push_back`, because it enables the possibility to create the objects inside the vector in place instead of copying.

### use the parallel std algorithms

In the end you could simply use the std::transform overloading for ExecutionPolicies rather than writing the stuff yourself on the base of threads. Have a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Answer (score 2):

```
#define NUM_OF_THREADS 8
#define VECTOR_SIZE    512
```

Don't use `#define` for constants or "functions" ([⧺ES.31](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es31-dont-use-macros-for-constants-or-functions))

---

```
using time_point = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point;
```

Good!  bring down just the stuff you need, and give it a friendly name.  I think

```
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point;
```

would be the same thing, and is the usual way of importing symbols from a library’s namespace.

---

```
assert(first.size() == second.size());
```

That will not do anything in a release build, you know.

If you really want checking, make a precondition that always works.  The GSL support library has `Expects` that can be programmed at compile time to assert, throw, or die.

---

In general `operator+` looks good!  You are using a value return, and you ensure NVRO takes place.  You reserve the vector size.  You use STL algorithms.

---

```
for (int i = 1; i <= VECTOR_SIZE; i++)
{
    first_vec.push_back(i);
    second_vec.push_back(i);
}
```

There is a standard algorithm for that.

---

```
time_point t1_seq = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
⋮
```

Use `auto` (almost everywhere).

since there is no code-movement barrier, your benchmark might not be accurate.

---

```
for (auto &thread : threads)
```

Good!  You use the range-`for` where you can.

Comment: It's okay to write out your answer and then post it. You don't get bonus points for answering as fast as possible.

Comment: Can you please explain me this *no code-movement barrier, your benchmark might not be accurate*? What does it mean code-movement barrier?

Comment: The compiler re-orders instructions.  It can and does even mix up what’s done before/after/during a function call!  Looking at that, I thought it might start preping the output formatting before it stops the clock.  In Microsoft’s compiler, for example, there are intrinsics `ReadWriteBarrier` etc. that prevent code movement across that boundary.  Using a standard sync mechanism with release (before) and acquire (coming out) should also prevent movement of code that reads and writes variables, though that doesn’t prevent *all* code movement in principle.